# What is the distinction between morphism and functor really?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, functors

According to nLab:

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/morphism

> In a general category, a morphism is an arrow between two objects.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor

> A functor is what goes between categories.

Basically, I observe these are the reason people (including here) claims "morphism and functor are different."

However, in single-sorted definition of a category,

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category

> The basic idea is that an object can be identified with its identity morphism.

This concept/definition is described in *Categories for the Working Mathematician* I.1 and XII.5.

So, in this scheme, when one claims

"a morphism is an arrow between two objects.",

which is equivalent to claim

"a morphism is an arrow between two categories."

since an object is identified with the identity morphism that is also a category(singleton).

So,

**morphism: an arrow between two categories**

**functor: what goes between categories**

and here, **"what" means morphism**

because

> defining a category which uses only one collection (representing the collection of morphisms)

Accordingly, **morphism == functor**, and usually we use the identical concept in different words everywhere (mostly with many confusions).

Some would say, "but, the scale of the perspective is different". Yes, I know, but I usually read explanations functor is somewhat special concept other than morphism, and never heard the difference is only perspective and relative.

Please tell me if there is any mistake. Thanks.

### EDIT

According to nLab article:

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor

---

### Definition

#### External definition

A **functor** $F$ from a **category** $C$ to a category $D$ is a map sending each **object** $x \in C$ to an object $F(x) \in D$ and each **morphism** $f : x \to y$ in $C$ to morphism $F(f) : F(x) \to F(y)$ in $D$, such that

- $F$ preserves **composition**: $F(g\circ f) = F(g)\circ F(f)$ whenever the left-hand side is well-defined,
- $F$ preserves **identity morphisms**: for each object $x \in C$, $F(1_x) = 1_{F(x)}$.

---

So, functor is often called "structure preserving".

However, there is an interesting article:

https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap

---

### The free theorem for fmap

When we write down the definition of Functor we carefully state two laws:

1. `fmap id = id`
2. `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)`

These are pretty well known in the Haskell community.

What is less well known is that the second actually follows from the first and parametricity, so you only need to sit down and prove one `Functor` law when you go to supply a `Functor`!

This is a “folklore” result, which I've used in conversation many times before, but it continues to surprise folks, so I decided to write up a slow, step by step proof of this result as it is a fun little exercise in equational reasoning.

To prove this we're going to need the [free theorem](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/%7Edreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf) for `fmap` and a few lemmas.

---

Comment: A functor is simply a morphism in the category of categories.

Comment: And a morphism is a morphism in the category of categories according to the single-sorted definition of a category, My question is about the distinction between morphism and functor really. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. They just are different objects. A morphism takes one object of a category to another. A functor takes one category to another.

Comment: @ElliotG I think I made my question pretty clear. Having said that, I also think your response is already discussed in my Question and denied.

Comment: @smooth_writing The word "is" does not mean "equals". I gather English is not your first language, but I hope you understand that when we write "an $X$ is a $Y$" we don't mean that "$X = Y$". There is a category whose objects are categories and morphisms are functors. There are other categories where objects might not be categories and morphisms might not be functors.

Comment: Also, to address the analogy with arrows, a morphism has no inherent structure, while a functor does. A functor isn't just an arrow between categories — it must preserve composition of morphisms, etc. A morphism by itself carries very little information.

Comment: @ElliotG Yeah, I know that is written everywhere. So according to your claim, a morphism must/can lose the structure of "object"? No, your simply repeat the explanation of funcor, but cannot deny the difference of morphism and functor.

Comment: @ElliotG I disagree. In the category of groups, morphisms are required to preserve the group operation. And in the category of schemes, morphisms have a bunch of structure, containing a continuous map between two topological spaces, and a bunch of ring homomorphisms. This way, functors are no different from other morphisms. Of course, this structure that some morphisms have isn't exposed at the categorical level, but that doesn't mean it isn't there when working in a specific category.

Comment: @Arthur yes but I assumed the question was about the definitions of morphisms/functors

Comment: @smooth_writing Sorry; I still don't understand what you're asking then. A priori, neither a morphism nor a functor is an object. You might get better results if you formulate a precise question next time. Have a good day.

Comment: @ElliotG Well in fact, the purpose of this question is to discus misconception like you have now. Obviously you are misguided by the explanation by various textbook, but the fact is in terms of preservation of structure, morphism and functor has no difference at all, but you said " a morphism has no inherent structure, while a functor does. "

Comment: What you just said is incorrect though. A priori, objects in a category have no structure, so there is no structure a morphism can preserve. I don't think you are interested in a productive conversation anymore, so, again, have a good day.

Comment: @ElliotG The reason you don't follow question is you have not read https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category

>The basic idea is that an object can be identified with its identity morphism.

Comment: @ElliotG >objects in a category have no structure, < Wrong.   You just don't have information at that point. Objects often have structures. You have a good day.

Comment: @ZhenLin >There are other categories where objects might not be categories< No, there are not, in in single-sorted definition of a category,

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category

>The basic idea is that an object can be identified with its identity morphism.

Comment: Fine. There are other categories where the morphisms are not functors, then.

Comment: @ZhenLin How so? Every morphisms are between categories(the minimal one is singleton), and every functors are between categories in the same manner.

Comment: Wrong. In the one-sorted definition of category morphisms are not "between" anything.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, can you give me an example? I want to know for instance.

Comment: It seems to me that you're observing that an object $x$ is just an identity morphism $\mathrm{id}_x$, which is essentially the same as the singleton set $\{\mathrm{id}_x\}$, which is a category under a unique category structure, and thus claiming that every morphism $f:x\to y$ is a functor, namely a functor between $\{\mathrm{id_x}\}$ and $\{\mathrm{id}_y\}$. But have you considered that there is *exactly one* functor between those categories, while there may be many morphisms $x\to y$?

Comment: @KevinArlin Correct. To be exact, every morphism is actually *f:X→Y*, and  for morphism: *f* , *X=  {idx}* and *Y={idy}*. By the way, I have edit my Question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to try approaching this from a different perspective.

I think you're interpreting the definition of functor and morphism incorrectly.

Let's review the definitions. (I'll use the single sorted definition of a category, although it's not really a good one for most purposes)

I'm going to stick to small categories to avoid foundational issues.

**A (small) category** consists of the following data. A set $C$ (whose elements we call the *morphisms* of $C$), two functions $s,t:C\to C$ called the source and target functions, and a composition function $\circ : C\times_{s,C,t} C\to C$ subject to the following axioms.

1. (Compatibility of sources and targets) For all $f\in C$, $s(s(f))=t(s(f))=s(f)$, and $t(t(f))=s(t(f))=t(f)$.
2. (Compatibility of sources/targets with composition) For all $f,g\in C$ with $s(g)=t(f)$, then $s(g\circ f)=s(f)$, and $t(g\circ f)=t(g)$.
3. (Identity) For all $f\in C$, $t(f)\circ f = f = f\circ s(f)$ (note that composition  is well defined, by Axiom 1).
4. (Associativity) For all $f,g,h\in C$ such that $s(h)=t(g)$, and $s(g)=t(f)$,
   $h\circ (g\circ f) = (h\circ g)\circ f$.

**Key point:**

When we say some mathematical object $f$ is a morphism, we mean that $f\in C$, where $C$ is a set equipped with a specific structure of a small category.

This is just like how when I say some mathematical object $v$ is a vector, I mean that $v$ belongs to a set $V$ equipped with some specific vector space structure on $V$.

In other words, I cannot say something is a morphism without being clear what category structure I consider the morphism to belong to!

Now in practice, there are many well known categories, and people usually just say things like $\phi$ is a morphism of groups, and take for granted that we can figure out which category structure on groups they are referring to.

In particular, morphisms are not "arrows between categories." In the single sorted definition, morphisms are *elements of some specified category*.

Really, if we were careful we would always say something like $f$ is a morphism of $C$, where $C$ is a specific category.

**Functors**

A functor (of single-sorted, small categories) $F:C\to D$ is a structure preserving function.

More concretely, $F$ is a function from $C$ to $D$ such that for all $f,g,h\in C$, $F$ satisfies
$s(F(f))=F(s(f))$, $t(F(f))=F(t(f))$, and if $s(h)=t(g)$, then $F(h\circ g) = F(h)\circ F(g)$.

Functors are simply functions which preserve structure.

**Key point:**

Functors are not "what goes between categories." They have a concrete definition.

Question: Are morphisms always functors? No, there's no reason to expect that the set of things which I happened to put a category structure on happened to be a set of functors.

Question: Are functors always morphisms? Again, no. A functor is simply a structure preserving function. I don't *have* to specify a category containing a given functor for the functor to be useful, and for me to do things with it. Of course, in practice, we often do want to define a category whose morphisms are functors, because we are often interested in composite functors, but we don't need to do so.

**Concluding point**

It seems to me that you've gotten side tracked by taking intuitive explanations of things as if they are rigorous definitions.
Mathematical terms and objects have mathematical definitions. Don't interpret intuitive explanations as definitions of things. Focus on the actual definitions.

Morphisms and functors have different (inequivalent!) definitions. They are very much not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The reason I made this question is I have a intuition (that is what you call) category theory is self-similar and scale invariance. A category looks self-similar in every scale, therefore I think "arrow" should be single instance.

Comment: Having said that, you say "Focus on the actual definitions." Fine, but I can point out a couple of possible mistake as a result of such an attitude.

Comment: (1) A functor (of single-sorted, small categories) F:C→D is a structure preserving function.

This gives a wrong "intuition" as if morphisms are not structure preserving function. In fact mrphisms do.

Comment: (2) More concretely, F is a function from C to D such that for all f,g,h∈C, F satisfies  

if s(h)=t(g), then F(h∘g)=F(h)∘F(g).

<< this is redundant In fact, this is the reason people keep claiming functors are structure preserving as if unlike morphisms.

The fact is if we map objects which are actually identity morphisms in single sorted definition, the composition lawy is automatically satisfied. See. https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap

Comment: Of course, "composition" of morphisms is not limited to "function composition", and composition law is described in the definition of morphism / category. So, this composition rule in terms of functor is redundant, at the same time, which is not appropriate to say as if only functor preserve composition structure.

Comment: *What is less well known is that the second actually follows from the first and parametricity, / This is a “folklore” result, which I've used in conversation many times before, but it continues to surprise folks,* https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap

The reason people are surprised and the false information becomes a "forklore" is they just swallow given definitions without considering what actually is. Eventually I might be wrong after all, but I just feel something is very wrong in the current situation.

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: What does "parametricity" mean or refer to? Lawvere, Rosebrugh refer to "parameterizations" but... Is it a mathematical term or something related to Haskell?

Answer (score 4):

In the category of sets, we call the morphisms "functions".

In the category of vector spaces over a given field, we call the morphisms "linear transformations".

In the category of groups, we call the morphisms "homomorphisms".

In the category of categories (which if I recall correctly isn't actually a thing), we would call the morphsims "functors". We do have things like the category of small categories, however. And in that case, the morphisms are really called "functors".

Functors are morphisms between categories, but there are too many of them to put all of them into a single category.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is  "What is the distinction between morphism and functor really?", so I prefer a direct answer, yours is not.

Comment: @smooth_writing But I did answer: A functor would be a morphsim if the category of categories were a thing. Of course, you can always have *a* category of categories (like the category of small categories), and in that case the morphisms are functors. So the only distinction is that there is no category that contains all functors simultaneously, the way there is a category that contains all functions (Set), and a category that contains all group homomorphisms (Group). Functors are morphisms, but there are too many of them to collect them all in a single category.

Comment: Ok, can you add the comment to your answer because the first version of the answer is far from the direct response.

Comment: @Arthur In my view there is no point in mentioning that the category of all categories is a problematic notion here. It only confuses matters.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, I agree. In this sense, a morphism (not only functor) is a morphism in the category of categories according to the single-sorted definition of a category, hence, there is no difference between morphism and functor.

Comment: @smooth_writing Well, if we ignore the issues of a category of categories as Zhen Lin siggests, then the distinction between functors and morphisms is that functors is **one type of morphisms**. Functors are morphisms between categories. Morphisms between other types of objects are not functors, but they are still morphisms. See my answer post for three commonly used examples of non-functor morphisms.

Comment: Your question at this point is a bit like asking "what is the difference between a function and a vector" because a function can be an element of a vector space, and a vector can be considered a function via translation.

Comment: @ElliotG The reason you response like that is, perhaps, you really didn't follow the context of  single-sorted definition of a category.

Comment: @Arthur >Morphisms between other types of objects are not functors,<  Sorry, I don't get it. Functors can be between any categories=objects, correct?

Comment: @Arthur >In the category of sets, we call the morphisms "functions".< functions are morphisms between categories as mentioned in my quesion.

Comment: @smooth_writing "function" and "functor" are two different words. As to your other remark, just no. A functor goes from one category to another category. Just like a function goes from one set to another set. Just like a linear transformation goes from one vector space to another vector space. Just like any other morphism goes from one object to another object **of the same type / within the same category** (i.e. from set to set, from topological space to topological space, from scheme to scheme, and so on, each in their own category).

Comment: I know they are two different words, and I'm saying "function" is a special case of "functor"="morphism". For "same type" I think you repeatedly mention endomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Functors take objects to objects; and morphisms to morphisms.  That is, a functor has categories as its domain and range.  In addition, certain conditions are satisfied by a functor.

Thus, as in @JohnDouma's comment, a functor is a type of morphism.